# How can I set noindex and nofollow metadata in Symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony, search-engine

I need to set noindex and nofollow metadata in Symfony 6 framework

Is there any native setting to do so?

Is it specifiable on the .yml section?

Thanks

I've tried to use robots.txt but the website is still visible if I search for it

Comment: **How** did you try that? Would you like to add this in the HTML markup (then do so) or using a header?

Comment: The most effective one. 

@NicoHaase I've tried to place the robots.txt in the website root folder but I think that the php interpreter doesn't elaborate the file, thus not telling search engines not to track the ws

Comment: Just FYI, if your site was already indexed it might take a while for engines to notice that you don't want it to be indexed, and also to purge. The recommended solution for that specific scenario is to use each engine's tool (such as Google Search Console) and submit your site/pages for immediate removal from the index.

Comment: For no indexing, did you see this? https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-automatic-search-engine-protection

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @ChrisHaas no, but infinitely thanks.
I'm aware that it take a while after putting on the protection set, but I've waited for one month and it is still visible. I'll try the Automatic Search Engine Protection

Comment: You should also read [Google's official position](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/block-indexing) on this. They use robots.txt _only_ for determining which URLs to not _crawl_, which is different than _index_. Once something is indexed, changes to that file only changes future crawls, not the current index. Also, if something was indexed, and you add a meta HTTP/HTML header, and you add that URL to robots.txt, Google will obey the latter which means it won't crawl and therefore notice the new meta attribute, so the URL will stay indexed.